# Comparing a single column in multiple data sets

Tags: r, classification

I am very new to R and I have a task to do. I appreciate any help. I have 3 data sets. Each data set has 4 columns. Example (Attached picture)

Now I need t compare the class section between 3 data sets and assign the most repeated class to that text. For example if text1 is assigned to class 0 in data set 1&2 but assigned as 2 in data set 3 then it should be assigned to class 0. If they are all the same so the class will be the same. The ideal thing would be to keep the same format and just update the class. Is there any easy way to do this?

```
   Class  Comment Term Text
    0      com1   aac   text1
    2      com2   aax   text2
    1      com3   vvx   text3
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Instead of a picture, try to make a small example that highlights the specific problem you're having.

Comment: oh I didnot notice you edited that. How can I bring it back?

Comment: Thanx. I just started here I really don't know how some of these functions work. The data sets have 4 dimensions (columns) and around 1000 row that are the same as well. The only difference is the class value for each row. So the idea is to have an output that compares and updates the class value for each row. I don't know if I am clear or not.. lol

Comment: My doubt is when they have the same frequency, where will it be assigned i.e. `Class 0, Class 1, Class2` for corresponding datasets

Comment: If the class has frequency 1 in data set one and two and 2 in the last data set, the frequency should be changed to 1 because the majority (2 data sets) have class 1. if all 3 are the same so it will not change.

Comment: You are repeating the same sentence in the description.  I meant if there is no majority, i.e. `text1` is assigned to 'Class1' for dataset1, `text1` is assigned to `Class2` for dataset2 and `text1` is assigned to `Class3` for dataset3

Comment: If there is no majority the class will be 0